# Check if a linux kernel was built with networking support

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, arm

Given a QEMU linux ARM/Mips Image, how could I go about ascertaining whether or not the kernel was built with networking support?

1. In cases where I cannot compile a binary for the platform, is there any kind of config file I can inspect?
2. Assuming I can compile a binary for the platform, how could I go about checking if there is support? What would happen if I made calls to sys_accept or sys_connect in that case? Would an error be thrown? Or would it just block in the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

From `https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt`, the `/proc/net` directory exists if the kernel has networking configured.